# UDP Server not able to send messages

Tags: c, network-programming

I'm trying to establish a UDP connection between the sender and receiver on the same host machine.The client is able to send the message but the server is unable to reply.Where is the error and how do I fix it?

I am guessing the error is with the argument list in send to of the receiver or recvfrom from sender.

SENDER CODE

```
void main()
   {
   int sockd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);  //socket creation
   if(sockd==-1)
   { printf("Socket function failed\n");
   }
   else
   { printf("Socket creation successfull\n");
   } 

   struct sockaddr_in sender;
   sender.sin_family=AF_INET;
   sender.sin_port=htons(6521);
   sender.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 


   int bindno=bind(sockd,(const struct sockaddr*)&sender,sizeof(sender));
   if(bindno==-1)
   { printf("Bind failure\n");
   }
   else
   { printf("Bind successfull\n");
   }

   struct sockaddr_in destaddr;
   destaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
   destaddr.sin_port=htons(9446);
   destaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

  char buf[100]="Hello from sender!";
  int sendno=sendto(sockd,buf,strlen(buf),0,(const struct sockaddr*)&destaddr,sizeof(destaddr));
 if(sendno==-1)
 { printf("Sending msg failed\n");
 }
 else
 { printf("Sending msg successful\n");
  }   

 char bufrecv[100];
 struct sockaddr_in recvaddr;
 int len;
 int recvno=recvfrom(sockd,bufrecv,sizeof(bufrecv),0,(struct sockaddr*)&recvaddr,&len);
 if(recvno==-1)
 { printf("Receive failed\n");
 }
 else
 { printf("Message received: %s",bufrecv);
 }
close(sockd);
}
```

RECEIVER CODE

```
 void main()
{
 int sockd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);  //socket creation
 if(sockd==-1)
 { printf("Socket function failed\n");
 }
 else
{ printf("Socket creation successfull\n");
}


struct sockaddr_in receiver;
receiver.sin_family=AF_INET;
receiver.sin_port=htons(9446);
receiver.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 

 int bindno=bind(sockd,(const struct sockaddr*)&receiver,sizeof(receiver));
 if(bindno==-1)
 { printf("Bind failure\n");
 }
 else
 { printf("Bind successfull\n");
 }

 char bufsndr[100];
 struct sockaddr_in sendaddr;
 int len;
 int recvno=recvfrom(sockd,bufsndr,sizeof(bufsndr),0,(struct sockaddr*)&sendaddr,&len);
 if(recvno==-1)
 { printf("Receive failed\n");
 }
 else
 { printf("Message received: %s",bufsndr);
 }

 char buf[100]="Hello from receiver!";
 int sendno=sendto(sockd,buf,strlen(buf),0,(const struct sockaddr*)&sendaddr,len);
 if(sendno==-1)
 { printf("Sending msg failed\n");
 }
 else
 { printf("Sending msg successful:%s\n",buf);
  }   

 close(sockd);
}
```

Comment: in the `recvfrom` function you need to specify the length of the structure you are passing, (in this case `struct sockaddr_in`) in len. The function will then return the actual bytes received in the same parameter

Comment: @RishikeshRaje so you mean I should initialize len to sizeof(sockaddr_in object) ?

Comment: It would be nice if you post the complete example, without stripping the headers, as your error can be in the lack of including some header file or like that.  PLEASE, READ [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)